# Combinations with items

Tags: combinatorics

given k sets of people each having n people.In how many ways can we put the people in  n elemented sets each having k people and there is exactly 1 person from each set

Comment: (k<n).
There is no order in the new sets and between the sets
$ (k+1)!$ .$ (n!)^k $?

Comment: Wait, do you want $m$ sets each of size $k$ such that each of these sets has one element from the original $k$ sets?

Comment: edited should be n instead of m

Comment: we have to have n sets each having k people and in each new set there is one person from each k set in the given problem

Comment: Ok,I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

take them out set by set. there are $n^k$ ways to take the first set since there are $n$ candidates from each of the $k$ sets, then there are $(n-1)^k$ ways to take the second set. all the way up until there are $1^k$ ways to take the $n$'th set. However we have overcounted because the order in which the sets are taken should not matter. Thus the answer should be didided by $n!$.

The final answer is then:

$$\frac{n^k(n-1)^k\dots (1)^k}{n!}=\frac{(n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(1)^k}{m!}=\frac{n!^k}{n!}=n!^{k-1}$$